# How can I delete an object which is the subject of a loop?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, ms-word

The problem I have is that the user is copying from one content control and pasting it into another accidentally. When extracting the data from this form, it then picks up that extra CC and therefore the value twice over.

When pulling the data I'm trying to see if a CC has a ParentCC and then delete it, but I keep getting

> Run time error 5825: Object has been deleted.

I can understand why but I'm unsure as to how get around it, nothing I've searched seems to work.

```
'With Word document Statement precedes this
For Each CCtrl In .ContentControls

    CCtrlText = CCtrl.Range.Text

    If Not CCtrl.ParentContentControl Is Nothing Then
        CCtrl.ParentContentControl.Range.Text = CCtrlText
        CCtrl.Delete
    End If
Next
```

How can I remove this content control which is duplicated inside the other and retain the input information?

Comment: Try something like this for I=0 to .contentcontrols.count, set CCTrl = .contentcontrols(I)

Answer (score 0):

So after some messing around and looking into how the local variables properties changed as a stepped through the code I have found that the line:

```
CCtrl.ParentContentControl.Range.Text = CCtrlText
```

Was in effect replacing the Content Control (CC) in it's ParentCC range property with the input text, and therefore deleting the duplicated CC.

`CCtrl.Delete` was trying to delete an object that had already been deleted and that swhy it was throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

I think with a foreach loop you can't alter the contents of the list/array without impacting the function of the loop.  If you instead use the indexers, it should allow you to alter the collection, since you are not impacting the loop (number to number):

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim c As ContentControl

For i = 1 To d.ContentControls.Count
  Set c = d.ContentControls(i)
  c.Delete
Next i
```